# I can't make a particle system in cycles render! :(

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

Please help! I'm using cycles render, version 1.79. When I try to make a particle system, I can't. I tried using blender render then changing, but then some options are grayed out and I need to change those. For example, I can't use emissions when changing render options. 
[image: No "add" option]

Comment: why don't you scroll up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

just scroll up on the tab then you'll find the add particle system option. Click on it and the thing will expand down the page

Comment: Ah. I feel stupid now.

Comment: it's ok we all make mistakes